# APIs are not responding via Azure APIM developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, custom-domain

Recently I have configured custom domain for APIM proxy URL. Now When test the APIs on APIM developer portal, API calls are not triggering. When I test this APIs from "POST MAN", it is working fine. Yes, this issue is not affecting any application. But appreciate your support to identify the issue.

Note : I have cleared the cache of the browser and tried.

Thanks,
Inzi

Comment: What response do you get in Portal? Would it be ok to share service name?

Comment: Additionally, you can capture the 2 requests using fiddler and compare.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin I am not getting any response on portal.

Comment: Would you be comfortable sharing a service name?

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin I have opened a ticket with MS APIM Product team. What you mean service name ? APIM name ?

Comment: @MohamedInfaaz yes, API Management service name.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and it works well. Take a look at Developer portal and postman to check if there are differences between headers and request url.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain).

Comment: Thanks Joey. I have rechecked the both URLs & parameters. Both are same.Still no luck.